# Get data from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the variable `$alldates`, which with `print_r` brings me the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 24. May 2016 08:30 - 17:00 [1] => 7. June 2016 08:30 - 17:00 ) )
```

I need to show the dates (which can be a lot more than two) in `PDF`, `ordered` under eachother like:

```
24. May 2016 08:30 - 17:00
7. June 2016 08:30 - 17:00
```

How to `get` the `dates` from the `array` and `display` them?

Comment: have you tried `foreach`?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($alldates as $index){
   echo $index."<br/>";
}
```

i'm not sure about your array , alternative way :

```
foreach ($alldates[0] as $index){
   echo $index."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear from the question, but the OP would probably have to loop over: `foreach ($alldates[0] as $index){` or use nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
foreach ($alldates as $date) {

   echo $date . '<br />';
}
```

or here thre is another way

```
$count = count($alldates);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

   echo $alldates[i] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop can be used if its multi-dimensional array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24. May 2016 08:30 - 17:00
            [1] => 7. June 2016 08:30 - 17:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24. May 2016 08:30 - 17:00
            [1] => 7. June 2016 08:30 - 17:00
        )

)

foreach ($alldates as $s_date){       
   foreach ($s_date as $n_date){
      echo $n_date."<br/>";  
   }
}
```